# Are SHA1 fingerprints secure enough to check device public keys in IoT Hub?

Tags: security, sha1, azure-iot-hub

As you know, SHA1 was broken last year (https://shattered.io).

But, in Azure IoT Hub and DPS SHA1 fingerprints are used to check that the device public key is reliable.

In theory, an attacker could find a pair private / public key values, different than the geniune, that would match with the genuine fingerprint stored on the IoT Hub / DPS.

Would that process suitable?
Why not to upgrade anyway to SHA256?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> In theory, an attacker could find a pair private / public key values, different than the geniune, that would match with the genuine fingerprint stored on the IoT Hub / DPS.

First: It's not that easy. Generating a pair of colliding messages is one thing; generating a pair of private keys whose public keys have the same hash is quite another. Keep in mind that the public key is generated from the private key; it can't be controlled directly.

Second: Even if you generate a pair of colliding public keys, so what? I can't immediately think of any way this would break the security of the service provider. It might get confused if you tried to register both key pairs, but that's about it.

Comment: The attacking scenario could be as follows:
1. I create a message using a private key whose fingerprint of its public key collides with geniune.
2. When the message is received by IoT Hub, checks if the fingerprint of the provided public key is the same that the fingerprint it had stored on register step (please note IoT Hub only stores fingerprint, not the whole public key.
3. IoT Hub validates as good the fingerprint and accepts (wrongly) the message.

Comment: Current attacks against SHA-1 only permit the creation of colliding pairs. There's no preimage attack yet; you can't create a collision against a message (or key) that you don't have control over.

Answer (score 0):

Both DPS as well as Azure IoT Hub support SHA256 thumbprints.

Comment: In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security states: 
"The thumbprint represents a SHA-1 hash of the X.509 certificate (stored using binary DER encoding)."

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. We will fix the documentation to show that IotHub accepts SHA256 thumbprints. SHA-1 thumbprints are supported for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, but still I something I don't understand, in the docs appears this example: 
PrimaryThumbprint = "921BC9694ADEB8929D4F7FE4B9A3A6DE58B0790B"

This is a SHA-1, not SHA-256!

Comment: Thanks again. We have fixed the example to show a SHA-256 thumbprint instead of SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this clarifying resource:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2015/02/16/azure-cloud-services-only-support-sha-1-thumbprint-algorithm/

It points the key difference between signing algorithm and thumbprint algorithm. SHA-1 vulnerability only affects signing algorithm, not thumbprint!